# Calling methods from other classes in cucumber

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I am using cucumber to automate tests on a website and I'm trying to call methods that exist in other classes (in other .rb files).  I have done this same process using calabash and I'm trying to find the equivalent way to do this in cucumber but I'm not having any luck.

After login, I will go to say 1 of 10 different pages.  Each of those pages has already been defined and there's a method defined in each of those pages that verifies the page by id/title...whatever.

I want to be able to call those verify methods from the login.rb file so that I am logging in AND verifying the landing page at the same time.  That way, if the landing page ever changes, I change it in ONE place vs. every scenario.

Something like this:

login.rb:

```
def sign_in(login)
    verify_login_page
    enter_credentials login
    click_login_button
    case login
        when 'dispatcher' then page(DispatcherList).verify_dispatcher_page
        when 'auditor' then page(MyAudits).verify_my_audits
    end
end
```

In my step file, I call on(LoginPage).sign_in(login) and pass it my variable but I can't find out how to call the verify methods that I have set up for each landing page.  page(DispatcherList) or on(DispatcherList) both give undefined method 'page' or 'on'.

I have used page() in Calabash and this works great.

Is there an equivalent way to do this in cucumber or does this type of code need to be placed in a global module?

I'm trying to not use global modules since all of the elements/logic has already been defined in separate rb files and we like this structure for debugging purposes.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions you may have!